# Got error: doesn’t connects with the database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, config

need help

Got an error, looks like this:

> “Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ‘Denis’@’91.200.40.82’ (using password: YES) in /home/h59695/data/www/art-hall.in.ua/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531”

So the problem is that I have downloaded the config.php from host and modified it on my local pc. Accidentaly after I modified that file I loaded it back onto the server and so my local modified config.php replaced the original file and afterwards I got an error ocurred, which says “Error establishing a database connection”.

Also I’ve replaced my local data in file with the Host data, but it did nothing and the error keeps happening

My hosting provider is ISP Manager

The page I need help with: http://art-hall.in.ua/

Comment: Log In your ISP Manager and check your DB name, username and pass. Access denied for user -> wrong username or pass

Answer (score -1):

Here is the file directly from wordpress repository, so you can reset your changes and to do it again.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php

Comment: Hello.
Thanks for the reply.

Can I ask for more details? Didn't get it